# Why only one method at a time can be active within each thread running in JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

can somebody explain why only one method at a time can be active within each thread running in JVM? Why not two or three, but only one?

Comment: Because if it could run two things at a time, they'd be called two threads.

Comment: Sounds like something philosophical...

Comment: Looks like a new OS design :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each thread runs code synchronously. A thread is only given more work to do once it has finished it's current allocation of work.

As to why there can only be one method 'active' at a time, a method can call other methods or return. Once a method has returned, it is obviously no longer active, similarly, once a method calls another, the called method becomes the active one.

Answer (score 6):

A thread by definition is something that executes code in a sequential way. So there is no way to execute more then one method in one thread. If you want to execute two or more methods in parallel, use multiple threads. You may want to have a look into the [Java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to learn about the basics of threads.

Answer (score 2):

The entire reason threads exist at all is so you can execute more than one thing concurrently. Every thread has its own stack and program counter so it can be in only one place in the code at any time.

Comment: so, the main reason is that you can only have one program counter for each thread?

Comment: @zum: The program counter is one reason. Another one is that a thread has it's own sector of memory.

Answer (score 2):

With multiple instructions per clock cycle, method inlining, CPU pipelining and instruction re-ordering, a single thread can execute instructions from multiple methods at once, however it should only do this when you see no difference. i.e. The idea is to improve performance without changing behaviour.